# Upgraded Ubuntu 19.10 -> 20.04 and my search bar is now BROKEN can't find apps etc

Tags: gnome, upgrade, 20.04, search

I just upgraded from 19.10 to 20.04 and now everything has disappeared when I click the dash search. This makes it impossible to get to software etc...
I tried all the usual 
sudo apt-get update, upgrade, reinstall. 
I reinstalled gnome. I rebooted unity. I rebooted the machine. I did recovery mode and ran all the utilities. I was able to open the snap store and software apps through terminal, but can no longer open apps using the search bar.
Any ideas?

Comment: I was able to get search back (mostly) by booting into Ubuntu, Linux 5.3.05 instead of 5.4.

Comment: I did an upgrade just now and it seemed to have resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Same as here. I did the same steps you mentioned and did not work. Remove and reinstall gnome-extensions does not works as well too.
It seems some gnome extension bugs the search dock. I tested removing the last one i had installed. Screenshot Tool. Reboot and it works fine for me!